# Temp table not being dropped in Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, temp-tables

I am creating a mysql temp table in my rails application (3.2). I attempt to manually drop the table by running the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP TEMPORARY TABLE `Example`")
```

For some reason the table is not being dropped and continues to exist even when I make a new request to the server. Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: Ok, so the table doesn't appear to exist anymore, however what was in the temp model seems to persist in memory somehow.

Comment: You would need to reload any models in memory based on temp in order to see 'fresh' values. i.e. my_model_based_on_temp.reload